# R error with spatial point data frame when using lapply

Tags: r, lapply, spdep

I have a list of lists called `flat_head`.

```
dput(flat_head)
structure(list(`0.25_0.05` = list(c(66, 102, 4.84), c(56, 75, 
3.63), c(15, 134, 0)), `0.25_0.1` = list(c(147, 27, 0), c(98, 
18, 4.84), c(141, 54, 4.84)), `0.5_0.05` = list(c(64, 130, 4.84
), c(61, 97, 4.84), c(58, 16, 4.84))), .Names = c("0.25_0.05", 
"0.25_0.1", "0.5_0.05"))
```

I wrote a small function to run through each list and calculate Moran's I from a spatial points data frame. It works for a single list but it throws an error when I use `lapply`.

```
require(spdep)
M_fun <-  function(x){
  x2 <- unlist(x[[1]])
  x3 <- matrix(x2,ncol = 3, byrow=TRUE)
  colnames(x3) <- c("x","y","prey")
  coords1<-as.data.frame(x3[,1:2])
  spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords1,as.data.frame(x3[,3]))
  nm <- knn2nb(knearneigh(spdf))
  all.linked <- max(unlist(nbdists(nm, spdf)))
  nb <- dnearneigh(spdf, 0, all.linked)
  colW <- nb2listw(nb, style="W")
  results1<-moran(spdf@data$`x3[, 3]`, colW, length(nb), Szero(colW))
  return(results1)
}
y<- M_fun(flat_head) # works
final<-lapply(flat_head, M_fun) # does not work
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y<- M_fun(flat_head) # works
final<-lapply(flat_head, M_fun) # does not work`

For these two to be equivalent you would have to have `y <- M_fun(flat_head[[1]])` or similar since `lapply()` applies the function to each element of the list.

At the moment my guess is that `y<- M_fun(flat_head)` is giving you the output of M_fun for just the first list of flat_head. This is because you have `x2 <- unlist(x[[1]])` in the first line of the function.

If you change this to `x2 <- unlist(x)` it should work.

Consider using `dput(flat_head)` to create a better reproducible example.

Comment: I edited to include `dput`. I think your solution is working.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Your example still gives `NaN` for the third list in `flat_head`. I don't know enough about your field but it appears to be because all values in third col of `0.5_0.05` are the same.